# Multiple NetApi calls failing inconsistently

Tags: c++, windows

We have a multi-threaded process which makes multiple calls to multiple target machines from a source machine using NetApi’s eg. NetServerGetInfo, LSAOpenPolicy, NetShareEnum, NetWKstaGetInfo, NetWKstaUserEnum etc… We make quite significant number of calls and have observed that over a period of time these calls fail. For example NetServerGetInfo starts returning error 53 after a while. This issue persist until we restart Workstation service or the machine. Accessing the target shares directly also does not work after such error is returned by our process.

The source machine from where we are making calls is a Win 2k8 R2 and the target machines are 2k3 servers.

We are suspecting some kind of issue with NetApi calls or some kind of handle leak.

Has anyone faced similar issues while using these APIs and managed to figure out a solution?

I found few references online for similar issues:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2networking/thread/9f93508c-71fa-4807-b41a-8f558563afe3/
Snippet from above link:
Experiencing the exact same issue as stated about except we have 2 Windows Server 2008 R2's acting as Terminal Servers connecting to Server 2003 Shares.  Rebooting the terminal servers seems to resolve the problem for about 2-4 days and then re-appears.  The XP/Vista/Win7 workstations on the network has no problem accessing the shares on the 2003 Server, only the 2008 R2 servers.

Connecting the the 2003 Shares using the FQDN or IP address works, but using \servername returns network path not found.  Setting up WINS on the network did not resolve this, or adding a static entry in the hosts file to the server.

There is no firewall software installed on the servers and we don't use Symantec products on the network (No Symantec Endpoint security).

Viewing of the eventlog also turned up the Event ID: 1006, could not validate DNS server, even though name resolution appears to be functioning without a problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816621
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296694%28WS.10%29.aspx
https://serverfault.com/questions/205043/windows-share-the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available